# Magento 2 REST API - Add Order Comment

Tags: magento2, api

I'm trying to update the order status and add an order comment. I've found by looking at the Swagger reference that the best endpoint for this is likely:

```
/rest/V1/orders/9/comments
```

To which I'm posting the following array to:

```
    {
    "statusHistory": {
        "comment": "Transferred",
        "created_at": "2018-06-01  15:22:04",
        "entity_id": 9,
        "is_customer_notified": 0,
        "is_visible_on_front": 1,
        "status": "transferred"
    }
}
```

However, when I check the order in Magento Admin it's updating the order status to "transferred" correctly but isn't actually adding a comment to the order at all.

Magento Version: 2.2.3

Answer (score 6):

For put comment in Magento 2 using API

**url**  `http://<magento-host>/rest/V1/orders/54/comments`

> Action type :: POST

**Data**

```
{
    "statusHistory": {
        "comment": "This is testing comment from API",
        "created_at": "2018-06-05  15:22:04",
        "parent_id": 54,
        "is_customer_notified": 0,
        "is_visible_on_front": 1,
        "status": "pending"
    }
}
```

**Header**

```
Authorization :: Bearer <Access Token>
```

**output** : it will return `Boolean` value.

**Explanation**

`status` is the order status, like - `pending`

`order_id` is the table increment id.
`parent_id` only has a value if you edit the order in the backend.
Here is how it works.

When you edit an order in the backend, the order is canceled and a new order is created, ending up with 2 orders.

In order to keep a link between these 2 orders, magento stores in the `parent_id` field of the second order the `order_id` of the original order.
That's why you will see on the second order view page in the backend a link to the original order.

Comment: So is there a way to update the status on an order without recreating the order? This behavior of recreating the order just to update a field makes little sense to me

Comment: @Adity Shah order state is not updating using this api. can u advise me how to add that?

Comment: Hi @NagarajuK - Can you please try PUT method? and please verify order_id and parent_id

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...

I was trying to pass what I thought the API was asking for which was the orders entity id. Instead I was supposed to pass the orders entity id as "parent_id".

Like so:

```
{
    "statusHistory": {
        "comment": "Transferred",
        "created_at": "2018-06-01  15:22:04",
        "parent_id": 9,
        "is_customer_notified": 0,
        "is_visible_on_front": 1,
        "status": "transferred"
    }
}
```

Why is there zero documentation on what these various fields mean? I've looked everywhere online and the best documentation I can find for the API is Swagger but it doesn't explain what the fields are.

Comment: I explained the input data field uses.

Comment: Wow! It works changing entity_id to parent_id. Terrible documentation by Magento and inconsistent API compared to other methods. Thanks for figuring that out.

Comment: @zaedred but order state is not changing. how do we specify order state in this API?